# What do $\min{[f,g]}$ and $\max{[f,g]}$ mean in my proof of continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

[image: w]

I must understand this proof of continuity. I understand the basics of continuity and algebra of continuity of limits.  So I add the picture of the proof such that it is in the book of Real Analysis.I would  really appreciate if someone could explain it to me as simple as possible. I'm struggling to understand it, What do   $\min{[f,g]}$ and $\max{[f,g]}$ mean? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\max(f,g)=\begin{cases}f \text{ if }f\ge g \\\\g\text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$

$\min(f,g)=\begin{cases}f \text{ if }f\le g \\\\g\text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$

Comment: Ok. But what about the min?

Comment: @Malu:  I edited to include that

Comment: Thank you. I m trying to figure things out. Probably this is a simple idea but I haven't seen this notation before.

Comment: What about intervals?.

Answer (score 3):

For every $x$ in a neighborhood of $a$, you define

$$\operatorname{max}\{f,g\}(x):=\operatorname{max}\{f(x), g(x)\}$$
Similarly for $\operatorname{min}\{f,g\}$.

Comment: For every x in a neighborhood of a, ok this is useful. Related to $x\rightarrow a$. We re talking about intervals. 

Answer (score 2):

These two functions are defined as follows: whenever $f(x) \geq g(x)$, we have
$$\max \lbrace f,g \rbrace (x):= f(x) $$
while, whenever $g(x) \geq f(x)$, we have:
$$ \max \lbrace f,g \rbrace (x):= g(x) $$
The function $\min \lbrace f,g \rbrace$ is defined analogously. Regarding the equations in the proof, see also: [How to show that $\max(f,g) =(f+g+|f-g|)/2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216042/how-to-show-that-maxf-g-fgf-g-2).

Comment: Ok. Thanks a little bit more clear.